# how can i replace an element in list of lists in python

Tags: python

i have a list of list like below
                   bo = [['7', '8', '9'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]
i wanted to a code that change an elemnt if it is found.for example if 9 is in the nested list i want 9 to be changed to letter "x" and the board will be like
                   bo=[['7', '8', 'x'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['1', '2', '3']]
please know that i am in introductory level.don't know about lambda or numpy.

Comment: the simplest solution is to use two for loops.. have you tried that already?

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension

```
def replace_num(lst, find_num, new_num):
  return [[new_num if x == find_num else x for x in sublist] for sublist in lst]

lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
print(replace_num(lst, 5, 25))

# Output: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 25, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
b=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
a = np.array(b)
b = np.where(a==3, "xx", a)
print(b)            
>>[['1' '2' 'xx'] ['4' '5' '6']]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Probably slower than the other solution but you can just write a loop:

```
b=[[1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7]]
test=4
new=2
for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(len(b[i])):
        if b[i][j] ==test:
            b[i][j]=new
```

Or if you use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,46,7]])
a[a==4]=2
```